# UITableView nested in ContainerView not highlighting

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicontainerview

I've created a UIViewController with a ContainerView that holds a UITableViewController. In the ParentViewController's ViewDidLoad() method I set up the parent child relationship between the two viewConrollers.

```
 guard let childView = childViewController.view else {
            return
        }
    addChildViewController(childViewController)

    containerView.addSubview(childView)
    ... add constraints ... 
    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

The UITableViewController is presented in the ContainerView. It is scrolling correctly, but the cell's do not highlight when tapped. Specifically, the animation where they change tint is not occurring. The delegate methods

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return true;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Oh no you didn't!");
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // stuff.. 
}
```

are all executing but the cell's tint never changes.

I've looked at the gestureRecognizers on the UITableView, and they seem to be in order, which you would expect considering the delegate methods are being triggered.

I've also run this both in the simulator and on my iPhone, and have observed the same behaviour on both.

Comment: Turns out it was just something stupid I overlooked, see the answer bellow by @phamot. Feel free to down vote this question, since it turned out not to have anything to do with nesting the TVC in the ContainerView or swift 3 after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 3.0:

You have to set the cell selection style

`cell.selectionStyle = .default`

Comment: Better double-check that... 1) The code posted in the question is Objective-C, not Swift, and 2) I don't think that's true in Swift 3.0 anyway.

Comment: Thanks, the project is both objective-C and Swift-3. The dataSource is in Obj-c. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something else to cause the rows not to highlight. I just gave it a try, both with "automating" it via Storyboard `UIContainerView` and via manually loading and adding the "contained" view. Also did it with both Swift and Objective-C `UITableViewController` classes.

Tapped Rows highlighted and un-highlighted as expected.

---

```
//
//  ManualContainerViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class ManualContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if true {
            //use swift table view controller

            if let childViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "containedTableVC") as? ContainedTableViewController {

                guard let childView = childViewController.view else { return }

                addChildViewController(childViewController)

                containerView.addSubview(childView)

                childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

                childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            }

        } else {
            // use Objective-C table view controller

            if let childViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "oc_containedTableVC") as? OCContainedTableViewController {

                guard let childView = childViewController.view else { return }

                addChildViewController(childViewController)

                containerView.addSubview(childView)

                childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
                childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

                childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

---

```
//
//  ContainedTableViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class ContainedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basicCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

---

```
//
//  OCContainedTableViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OCContainedTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

---

```
//
//  OCContainedTableViewController.m
//

#import "OCContainedTableViewController.h"

@interface OCContainedTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation OCContainedTableViewController

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"oc_basicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %ld / Row: %ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```